# How to create a controller action that allows a hashtag instead of questionmark in the query string

Tags: .net-core, google-oauth, asp.net-core-8

I am trying to get Google OAuth to work in a Blazor Server App.  Note that what I need is NOT login functionality.  Instead, I want to call the Calendar API for a user, and the end user needs to authorize this which, as I understand it, is a different user flow.

In this user flow, the user is directed to a url like this:

`https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar&include_granted_scopes=true&response_type=token&state=12345&redirect_uri=https%3A//localhost:7115/api/gauth&client_id=test.apps.googleusercontent.com`
`

This initiates the Google Authorization Prompt and the user authorizes it, and then google sends a callback to the redirect_uri which is included in the above url.

The problem is that the callback querystring is formatted like this according to the documentation:  `https://oauth2.example.com/callback#access_token=xyz&token_type=Bearer&expires_in=3600`

Note the use of the hashtag, instead of the questionmark.  The callback is a Controller method, not a browser, so it ignores everything after the hashtag.  Thus, the controller action does not get any of the parameters.

```
[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Route("api")]
[ApiController]
public class GoogleScopeAuth : ControllerBase
{
    
    [HttpGet("gauth")]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Get(string? access_token = null, string? token_type = null, BigInteger? expires_in = null, string? state = null, string? error = null )
    {
        Console.WriteLine(access_token);
        Console.WriteLine(token_type);
        Console.WriteLine(expires_in);
        Console.WriteLine(state);
        return Ok();
    }
}
```

How do I configure this so that the hashtag is converted to a question mark so it get properly processed?

I am a newby at Google OAuth, so if I am missing something, let me know.

What I am trying to do is capture the access token so I can use it to keep the app's calendar in sync with the users Google Calendar (insert Events into the Google Calendar).

[The Google Docs](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/javascript-implicit-flow)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Query Strings vs. Fragments

> How do I configure this so that the hashtag is converted to a question mark so it gets properly processed?

You can't. `?`'s are query strings. `#`'s are fragments.

The clear difference is that `#` fragments are NOT part of the HTTP request itself. Think of it more like a bookmark that *only the browser* is aware of. Fragments can't be read from the HTTP request. So, you can't read the token after the `#`, nor can you tell the browser, the identity provider or the HTTP to do it differently.

[Learn More](https://blog.httpwatch.com/2011/03/01/6-things-you-should-know-about-fragment-urls/)

### OIDC and authorization flows

Based on the format of the query string, I'm guessing you're trying to use "implicit grant" authentication flow. This is not recommended.

> Is OAuth Implicit flow dead?
> https://developer.okta.com/blog/2019/05/01/is-the-oauth-implicit-flow-dead

> *Microsoft doesn't recommend using Implicit grant.*
> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/webassembly/?view=aspnetcore-8.0#use-the-authorization-code-flow-with-pkce

### Blazor

From what I found, Implicit flow in Blazor is broken. I found the following [GitHub issue](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/25453) which is closed due to inactivity. Based on the information above, I would GUESS it's broke and a won't fix unless there is a necessary amount of demand.

Use the authorization code flow to authenticate and access the Google APIs. More information can be found here.

> https://blazorschool.com/tutorial/blazor-server/dotnet7/authentication-with-google-oauth-700535